# String from codebehind to array in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

Hi all i have code that reads from a DB and populates a string in the code behind

```
List<string> rows = new List<string>();
    DataTable prods = common.GetDataTable("vStoreProduct", new string[] { "stpt_Name" }, "stpt_CompanyId = " + company.CompanyId.ToString() + " AND stpt_Deleted is null");

    foreach (DataRow row in prods.Rows)
    {

        prodNames += "\"" + row["stpt_Name"].ToString().Trim() + "\",";
    }
    string cleanedNanes =  prodNames.Substring(0, prodNames.Length - 1);
    prodNames = "[" + cleanedNanes + "]";
```

This produces something like ["Test1","Test2"]

In javascript i have

```
var availableTags = '<% =prodNames %>';

alert(availableTags);
```

How can i access this like an array in javascript like

```
alert(availableTags[5]);
```

and get the full item at the given index.

Thanks any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes:

```
var availableTags = <% =prodNames %>;
```

With the quotes there, you're creating a JavaScript string.  Without them, you've got a JavaScript array constant.

Comment: Thanks for this @Pointy - Even though I answered this question I just learnt something new (Confirmed in js console).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to split the variable from .NET into a JS array.

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Example based on your code:

```
var availableTags = '<% =prodNames %>';
var mySplitResult = availableTags .split(",");
alert(mySplitResult[1]);
```

Comment: This is silly; why not just leave out the quotes from the variable initialization in the first place?  Also, [please consider avoiding w3schools.com](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: considering he has the surrounding [ and ], yes he'd have an array, versus just a string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe split() will do what you want:

```
    var availableTagsResult = availableTags.split(",");
    alert(availableTagsResult[1]) //Display element 1
```

This will create an array from the string which has been split on `,`

Comment: And what about the square brackets?

Comment: I'm not providing an exact solution - rather pointing the OP in the right direction

Comment: Well, if the OP simply initialized the variable without the single quotes, then it would be an array without any need for string manipulation.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks, I didn't know that, you've earned by upvote